# delicious clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for an Open Source delicious clone written in ruby on rails, is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

This project looks like it may be similar to what you are looking for:
http://www.steve.org.uk/Software/bookmarks/

Answer (score 1):

http://communityengine.org/ has some bookmarking features plus all of the other pluming that you need.

Answer (score 1):

[Feedmarker](http://rubyforge.org/projects/feedmarker/i) would be the first that comes to mind. [Here](http://www.feedmarker.com/) is a copy of it running.

A non open source solution would be to look at [Clone Stop](http://www.clonestop.com). I can not attest to the quality of their software but if your stuck then you may want to give them a try.